# Operator monotone functions

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

By definition, I know that a function $f$ is operator monotone if $A - B \geq 0 \Rightarrow f(A) - f(B) \geq 0$. For instance, we have $A^2 \leq B^2 \Rightarrow A \leq B$ because the root function is operator monotone. However, does this also imply that $A^{1/2} \leq 2A^{1/2}$?

Comment: That is wrong even for scalar $A$ (take $A=1/4$). Did you mistype the problem statement?

Comment: My mistake, I did. Changed it now.

Comment: $A^{1/2} \leq 2A^{1/2}$ if and only if $0 \leq A^{1/2}$ (subtracting $A^{1/2}$ from both sides). So this is true.